# How to call another method in mock object

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

I have object Panel inside is Methods

```
protected Confirmation confim() {
    Confirmation confirmation = new Confirmation() {
        @Override
        public void onConfirm() {
            doCancel();
        }
    };

    return confirmation;        
}

protected void doCancel() {
    ....
}
```

and i need to check That confirm() call doCancel Method

My Test

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Panel panel = Mockito.mock(Panel.class);

    Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(panel).confirm();
    Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(panel).cancel();

    panel.confirm();

    Mockito.verify(panel).cancel();
}`
```

The problem is that `cancel()` is never called... maybe it is because `OnConfirm()` is an overidden method and it takes a mock... or something... Can some one help how to test?

P.S. Panel must be Mocked.

problem was that o dont call   panel.confirm().onConfirm();
this is stupid mistake.. 
so please remove this Question..

Comment: ITs calling a method called `doCancel` not cancel, is this a typo or is `cancel()` called within `doCancel`

Comment: it was stupid mistake because i dont call   panel.confirm().onConfirm(); so please remove this question

Answer (score 4):

```
 @Test
public void test() {
    Panel panel = Mockito.mock(Panel.class);

    Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(panel).confirm();
    Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(panel).cancel();

        panel.confirm().onConfirm();

    Mockito.verify(panel).cancel();
}`
```

Comment: thanks i found it also... but too late it is stupid mistake.. this Question  should be deleted

Comment: @x3mik Generally we dont delete questions for that reason, just accept the answer and if someone else makes the same mistake this may help them